# Neo4J taking out long-lived locks in non-query transaction

Tags: neo4j

In our application we occasionally add around 10,000 nodes and 100,000 relationships to a Neo4J graph over the course of a few minutes, and then `DETACH DELETE` many of them a few minutes later. Previously the delete query was very quick (<100ms), but after a small change to our data model and some of our other queries (which are not running at the time), it now often blocks for minutes before completing.

While this blocking is happening there are no other queries running, and I have an export from Halin showing all the transactions that are happening at the time. It's difficult to reproduce here, but in summary there are exactly two transactions going on, one of which is my delete query. The delete query is stated to be blocked by the other one, which has 7 locks out, is in the Running state, and has no attached query or client at all. I imagine this means that it's an internal Neo4J process. It has 0 cpu time, and its entire 180s runtime is accounted for by idle time. There's no other information given.

What could be causing this transaction to lock the nodes that I want to delete for such a long time with no queries running?

---

**What I've tried**:

Using `apoc.periodic.iterate` and `apoc.periodic.commit` to split the query into smaller chunks - the inner queries end up locked

Looking in the query logs - difficult to be sure but I can't see any evidence of the internal transaction

Looking in the debug logs - records of garbage collections (always around 300ms) and some graph algorithms running, but never while this query is blocked, and nothing else relevant

---

**Other info**:

Neo4J version: 3.5.18-enterprise (docker)

Cluster mode: HA cluster with 2 nodes (also reproduced with only 1 node)

Answer (score -1):

It turned out that there was a query a few minutes before that had been set going and then the client disconnected (missing `await` in C#). I still don't quite understand why this caused the observations, but my guess is that Neo4j put the query into a weird state after the client disconnected, and then some part of it ended up waiting for the transaction timeout before releasing its locks.